# Release Celery lock when transaction is committed

Tags: python, django, locking, celery

I use a Celery task in my Django project with a lock as described in [this article](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time). It works great, but my task creates an object and I don't want that the lock was released before the object is committed in the database. How can I change this context manager to wait until the objects in the task are committed?

```
@contextmanager
def lock(lock_id, oid, expire=600):
    timeout_at = monotonic() + expire - 3
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, expire)
    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        if monotonic() < timeout_at:
            cache.delete(lock_id)

@celery.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def my_task(self, object_id):
    with lock('my_task.{}'.format(object_id), self.app.oid) as acquired, transaction.atomic():
        if not acquired:
            self.retry(countdown=1)
        def on_commit():
            # release the lock only in this moment
            pass
        transaction.on_commit(on_commit)
        MyModel.objects.create(object_id=object_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This context manager creates a lock and wraps a body in a transaction. It releases the lock only when the transaction was committed or an exception (except `celery.exceptions.Retry`) was raised.

As noted in Celery docs:

> In order for this to work correctly you need to be using a cache backend where the .add operation is atomic. memcached is known to work well for this purpose.

```
from celery.exceptions import Retry
from contextlib import contextmanager
from time import monotonic
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db import transaction


@contextmanager
def lock_transaction(lock_id, oid, expire=600):
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, expire)
    timeout_at = monotonic() + expire - 3
    is_retry = False

    def on_commit():
        if not is_retry and monotonic() < timeout_at:
            cache.delete(lock_id)

    with transaction.atomic():
        transaction.on_commit(on_commit)
        try:
            yield status
        except Retry as e:
            is_retry = True
        except:
            if monotonic() < timeout_at:
                cache.delete(lock_id)
            raise
```

An example of using:

```
@celery.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True, max_retries=90, time_limit=60)
def create_or_add_counter_task(self, object_id):
    with lock_transaction('object_id.{}'.format(object_id), self.app.oid) as acquired:
        if not acquired:
            self.retry(countdown=1)
        try:
            obj = MyModel.objects.get(object_id=object_id)
            obj.counter += 1
            obj.save()
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            MyModel.objects.create(object_id=object_id)
```